# PHP Oracle connection

Tags: php, oracle

I am attempting to write some connection code with PHP to a Oracle database my school is hosting.

I'm using oci_connect() at the moment to make this connection, but it is failing.

`$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'hostname/SID');`

I can access the oracle database through sqlDeveloper, as well as phpmyadmin, so I know the login information is correct.

I checked the oracle version with select `* from v$version;`, it shows as 12c Enterprise.

What is wrong with my php code for connecting? Is there a better way to make an oracle connection through PHP?

This is the test code I'm running, from http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php

```
 <?php
echo "running";
$conn = oci_connect("username", "paswwrod", "address/SID");
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();   // For oci_connect errors do not pass a handle
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message']), E_USER_ERROR);
}
echo "ending";


?>
```

The string "running" gets echoed, but "ending" does not, the script just stops working when it attempts oci_connect()

Comment: how is it failing? what error message do you get? are you certain OCI8-support is installed and enabled?

Comment: Can you please add the error that is thrown by oci_connect()? It can be accessed by oci_error().

Comment: @MiroslavDuník I don't get an error, the script just stops working. I'll update the top post with the test code I'm using.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I'm not receiving any error, the script just dies. I'll try to check for OCI8, this is not a server I manage, I only can attempt to connect.

Answer (score 0):

have you also tried including the port number to the oracle db server like so?

`$conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "localhost:1234/xe");`